# How to edit raw HTML with Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey before it is parsed by browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Does greasemonkey or tampermonkey have functionality that lets me edit the raw HTML response before it gets passed to the browser?

I'm trying to do this in an attempt to modify an inline script before it executes. This solution must work on both Firefox and Chrome so something like beforescriptexecute won't work because chrome doesn't support it yet.

If not, is there an extension that does provide this functionality that is available to both browsers?

Comment: This is (still!) not fully possible in Chrome, even for an extension, IIRC.  You can block scripts if they have a `src` attribute, but embedded scripts are another matter on Chrome.  I need to double-check a few things before posting a proper answer.  (Not a priority at the mo.) This topic has been discussed much;  Search around more.

Comment: Oh I've searched for hours on end. I've probably read every topic concerning greasemonkey at all on this site heh. I'm open to writing my own extension if need be. Surely a solution lies in that domain? The script in question is inline and therefore has no src attribute, but I would be interested in knowning how you would block an external script. I feel like I've read something on it but probably deemed it irrelevant at the time.

Comment: The FF/GM solution is easy, and I've a couple answers that address that.  But for Chrome, even extensions have lousy support for: iframes, `<script>` tag manipulation, and `document-start`.  There may be one approach that (now) works.  I need to run some searches and tests.  Might do so in a few hours -- low priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: No.

Longer answer:  Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey operate on editing the page has loaded, not at any time prior to that.  So, preventing a script from executing isn't going to happen.  Neither of these tools can change the code before it's run, it only alters once it has run and can inject certain scripts into the page after it's loaded that affect the data displayed or the appearance.   The best you could do is update or replace what's displayed based on the inline script, but it's still going to get sent initially.